# RegisterBackButtonAction working on many views

Tags: angularjs

For a `view X` I have a controller called `ControllerX`.

Here is a snippet from `controllerX` to listen to hardware back button event:

```
$ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(someFunc, 100);
```

Now the problem is when I navigate to any other page or view from `view X` then any events on hardware button on the new page still responds by executing someFunc that I had defined and used in `ControllerX`.

How should I remove that response for all my views except `view X`?

Answer (score 7):

```
var deregister = $ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(
        function () {
            console.log("close the popup")
        }, 100
);
//Then when this scope is destroyed, remove the function
$scope.$on('$destroy', deregister)
```

Store your back button registration in a variable -> destroys the function if the view gets destroyed.

Source: [ionic forum](http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/registerbackbuttonaction-working-on-many-views/4751/3)